# Ada lookup table not working when calling Ada from C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ada, gnat

I'm working on some Ada code which I have to call from C and I've encountered a problem which I can't solve and don't know why it's happening.

Here is a test project to illustrate the problem:

lookup.ads

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package lookup is
    procedure Printf(str : in Interfaces.C.char_array; i : in Positive);
    pragma Import(C, printf, "printf");

    procedure PrintLookup;
    pragma Export(C, PrintLookup, "print_lookup");
end lookup;
```

lookup.adb

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package body lookup is

    -- Month_Length : constant array (1..12) of Positive := (31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);

    Month_Length : constant array (1..12) of Positive := (4 | 6 | 9 | 11 => 30, 2 => 28, others => 31);

    procedure PrintLookup is
    begin

        printf("Month_Length(5): %d"&To_C(ascii.LF)&To_C(ascii.NUL), Month_Length(5));

    end PrintLookup;

end lookup;
```

main.adb

```
with lookup;

procedure main is
begin
    lookup.PrintLookup;
end main;
```

main.c

```
extern void print_lookup();

int main()
{
    print_lookup();
    return 0;
}
```

And I have a simple makefile to build it:

```
BUILD=ada

GM=gnatmake
CC=gcc
LIB=-L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/adalib


ifeq ($(BUILD),ada)
main:
    $(GM) lookup.adb main.adb
else
main: lookup.o main.o
    $(CC) $(LIB) lookup.o main.o -o $@ -lgnat

lookup.o:
    $(GM) lookup.adb

main.o:
    $(CC) -c main.c
endif


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f lookup.ali lookup.o
    rm -f main.ali main.o
    rm -f main
```

The makefile will generate an executable, called **main**. If the **BUILD** variable in the first line of the makefile is set to *ada*, it will use the Ada *main.adb*, otherwise the C *main.c*

Now, here comes the problem: if in the *lookup.adb* I use the first variant of the *Month_Length* array (which is commented out right now), I get the following output for both mains, which is correct:

> Month_Length(5): 31

But in case of the other array (which is called a lookup table), the C variant returns 0:

> Month_Length(5): 0

Does anyone have any idea why the lookup table array returns 0 when called from C?
Does anyone encountered this issue?
What am I missing?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: To cite  [https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html]     
:
"  `adainit`

    You must call this routine to initialize the Ada part of the program by calling the necessary elaboration routines. A call to adainit is required before the first call to an Ada subprogram."

Comment: That is true, thanks for the hint, I've posted an answer on how i managed to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Vroomfondel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819452/vroomfondel) mentioned in the comment, *adainit* must be called to initilise ADA.
Here are the modifications I made to get this working:

Here is the makefile:

```
BUILD=c

GM=gnatmake
GB=gnatbind
CC=gcc
LIB=-L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/adalib


ifeq ($(BUILD),ada)
main:
    $(GM) lookup.adb main.adb
else
main: lookup.o main.o
    $(CC) $(LIB) lookup.o b~lookup.o main.o -o $@ -lgnat

lookup.o:
    $(GM) lookup.adb
    $(GB) -n lookup.ali
    $(GM) b~lookup.adb

main.o:
    $(CC) -c main.c
endif


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f lookup.ali lookup.o
    rm -f b~lookup.*
    rm -f main.ali main.o
    rm -f main
```

*gnatbind* generates the *b~lookup.ads* and *b~lookup.adb* files which will contain the *adainit()* and *adafinal()* functions, then I've built them with *gnatmake* (I had to build because i'm not using *gnatlink*) and I've included the generated *b~lookup.o* file in the linking part.

The *main.c* had to be modified as follows (simply calling the init and final functions before and after the ADA call):

```
extern void print_lookup();
extern void adainit();
extern void adafinal();

int main()
{
    adainit();
    print_lookup();
    adafinal();

    return 0;
}
```

The rest remains the same.

Comment: the ada lib elaboration is often forgotten. To my knowledge, there is a mean to force elaboration code to be automagically executed when loading library. Can't remember the details right now ...

Comment: @LoneWanderer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821216/40851) - from "A way round the second problem ..."

Answer (score 2):

As a complement answer, I remembered that there was an alternative that would make the call to init() automatically.

Simon Wright pointed out his detailed answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821216/40851)

> When a DLL is loaded, Windows systematically invokes a routine called DllMain. It would therefore be possible to call adainit directly from DllMain without having to provide an explicit initialization routine.
>   Unfortunately, it is not possible to call adainit from the DllMain if your program has library level tasks because access to the DllMain entry point is serialized by the system (that is, only a single thread can execute “through” it at a time), which means that the GNAT run time will deadlock waiting for the newly created task to complete its initialization.

see [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Ada-DLLs-and-Elaboration.html)

one can also have a look at detailed approach [here](https://gnu.huihoo.org/gcc/gcc-3.3.6/gnat_ug_unx/Creating-an-Ada-Library-to-be-Used-in-a-Non_002dAda-Context.html)